# Reducer In React Native Not Working (Not A Function)

Tags: javascript, redux, react-native, redux-reducers

Currently, I'm working on react native and using Redux

I'm facing a problem, when dispatching the reducer, it saying not a function.

here's how I configure the store

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import navReducer from "./slices/navSlice";

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    nav: navReducer,
  },
});
```

here's my reducer

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const initialState = {
  origin: null,
  destination: null,
  travelTimeInformation: null,
};

export const navSlice = createSlice({
  name: "nav",
  initialState,
  reducer: {
    setOrigin: (state, action) => {
      state.origin = action.payload;
    },
    setDestination: (state, action) => {
      state.destination = action.payload;
    },
    setTravelTimeInformation: (state, action) => {
      state.travelTimeInformation = action.payload;
    },
  },
});

export const { setOrigin, setDestination, setTravelTimeInformation } =
  navSlice.actions;

export const selectOrigin = (state) => state.nav.origin; 
export const selecDestination = (state) => state.nav.destination;
export const selectTravelTimeInformation = (state) =>
  state.nav.travelTimeInformation;

export default navSlice.reducer;
```

calling the store in App.js

```
import React from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import HomeScreen from "./screens/HomeScreen";
import { store } from "./store";
import { SafeAreaProvider } from "react-native-safe-area-context";
import "react-native-gesture-handler";
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { createStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/stack";
import MapScreen from "./screens/MapScreen";

export default function App() {
  const Stack = createStackNavigator();
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>  <<-- calling in here
      <NavigationContainer>
        <SafeAreaProvider>
          <Stack.Navigator>
            <Stack.Screen
              name="HomeScreen"
              component={HomeScreen}
              options={{ headerShown: false }}
            />
            <Stack.Screen
              name="MapScreen"
              component={MapScreen}
              options={{ headerShown: false }}
            />
          </Stack.Navigator>
        </SafeAreaProvider>
      </NavigationContainer>
    </Provider>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
});
```

here the component that is using the reducer (HomeScreen.js)

```
import React from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, SafeAreaView, Image } from "react-native";
import tw from "tailwind-react-native-classnames";
import NavOptions from "../components/NavOptions";
import { GooglePlacesAutocomplete } from "react-native-google-places-autocomplete";
import { GOOGLE_MAPS_APIKEY } from "@env";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { setDestination, setOrigin } from "../slices/navSlice";

const HomeScreen = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={tw`bg-white h-full`}>
      <View style={tw`p-5`}>
        <GooglePlacesAutocomplete
          placeholder="Where From"
          styles={{
            container: {
              flex: 0,
            },
            textInput: {
              fontSize: 18,
            },
          }}
          onPress={(data, details = null) => {
            dispatch(
              **setOrigin({** // <<--this line says setOrigin is not a function
                location: details.geometry.location,
                description: data.description,
              })
            );
            dispatch(setDestination(null));
          }}
          fetchDetails={true}
          returnKeyType={"search"}
          enablePoweredByContainer={false}
          minLength={2}
          query={{
            key: GOOGLE_MAPS_APIKEY,
            language: "en",
          }}
          nearbyPlacesAPI="GooglePlacesSearch"
          debounce={400}
        />

        <NavOptions />
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

export default HomeScreen;
```

error message

```
(0, _navSlice.setOrigin) is not a function. (In '(0, _navSlice.setOrigin)({
          location: details.geometry.location,
          description: data.description
        })', '(0, _navSlice.setOrigin)' is undefined)
at node_modules\react-native-google-places-autocomplete\GooglePlacesAutocomplete.js:268:19 in request.onreadystatechange
at node_modules\event-target-shim\dist\event-target-shim.js:818:20 in EventTarget.prototype.dispatchEvent
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Network\XMLHttpRequest.js:592:4 in setReadyState
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Network\XMLHttpRequest.js:395:6 in __didCompleteResponse
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\vendor\emitter\EventEmitter.js:189:10 in emit
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:416:4 in __callFunction
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:109:6 in __guard$argument_0
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:364:10 in __guard
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:108:4 in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
```

When I press F12 on the `setOrigin` function, it's pointing to the right file.

What am I missing?

Comment: Should the property passed in to createSlice be `reducers` (with an s)?  https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createslice

Comment: omg, actually i read that page many time, didnt find any, thanks btw

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The error stating that setOrigin is not a function is resolved by naming the reducers object inside navSlice as "reducers" with an "s" instead of "reducer". Thank you and keep it up